# Weird View in Blender Render view, black object in Object while moving, transparent render, Eevee

Tags: rendering, materials, light

The problem is this: In the render view it seems that a kind of shadow of the object remains in the object itself when you turn around the object. It's dark gray. Materials and lights stop working.
After I press f12 the image is rendered but the object is rendered transparent.
What can I do?

I have already completely reinstalled Blender.

https://gyazo.com/162b9c83c187ada0c840f3ec57b1d238
And after moving it a bit:
https://gyazo.com/1a82380907ab00fb1215f805229acc19
And the render:
https://gyazo.com/b895d9fd28b06e82e91edb0beb3bda84

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem with the new AMD drivers. You can either degrade them, but i recommend something else. Go to render setting, then find Performance --> High Quality Normals. Enable it and the problems should be gone.

[image]

Comment: You saved my day, my week and everything else.. Thanks a lot !!

Comment: No problem, this is a thing that is very common today